# How to implement dependency property value inheritance in different control types

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

A have a collection of custom controls I'm creating that each have base classes of their respective controls. Because they each have different base controls, they can't share the exact same dependency property. Is it possible to link dependency properties together so that they can cascade from each other? (Not sure if I'm using the term cascade correctly grammar-wise)

```
public class RCTWindow : ContentControl {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RemapColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "RemapColor",
        typeof(RemapColors),
        typeof(RCTWindow),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            RemapColors.SeaGreen,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
            new PropertyChangedCallback(OnVisualChanged)));
    //...
}
public class RCTButton : Button {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RemapColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "RemapColor",
        typeof(RemapColors),
        typeof(RCTButton),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            RemapColors.SeaGreen,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
            new PropertyChangedCallback(OnVisualChanged)));
    //...
}
```

Here's the xaml. When setting the parent control's remap color, the button does not cascade it by default.

```
<local:RCTWindow RemapColor="IndianRed">
    <local:RCTButton/>
</local:RCTWindow>
```

Comment: It doesn't sound like you are actually talking about inheritance here.  It sounds more like you want property values to "cascade" from parent to child, similar to how CSS works, is that correct?  You want the `RemapColor` value that you set on the `RCTWindow` to show on the `RCTButton`.

Comment: Yes this is correct, I guess I didn't understand the correct term for it. I'll update the title and description.

Comment: I would suggest "How to cascade DependancyProperty values from parent to child controls".  I'm not sure if there is an actual official name for this.

Comment: [This MSDN atricle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/property-value-inheritance) looks like what you want.

Comment: How is this cascading colouring supposed to work? Is the colour going to be applied to all children bellow the control that declared your property?

Comment: Correct. I just want to simplify control coloring so that specifying the same color property for every child is unneeded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not declare multiple indepedent attached properties, because there won't be any property value inheritance between them.

Instead, declare a single attached property, and use `DependencyProperty.AddOwner` in the control classes.

```
public static class RCT
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RemapColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "RemapColor", typeof(RemapColors), typeof(RCT),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(RemapColors.SeaGreen,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits |
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public static RemapColors GetRemapColor(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (RemapColors)obj.GetValue(RemapColorProperty);
    }

    public static void SetRemapColor(DependencyObject obj, RemapColors value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(RemapColorProperty, value);
    }
}

public class RCTButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RemapColorProperty =
        RCT.RemapColorProperty.AddOwner(
            typeof(RCTButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnVisualChanged));

    public RemapColors RemapColor
    {
        get { return (RemapColors)GetValue(RemapColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RemapColorProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnVisualChanged(
        DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("RCTButton.OnVisualChanged: {0}", ((RCTButton)obj).RemapColor);
    }
}

public class RCTWindow : ContentControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RemapColorProperty =
        RCT.RemapColorProperty.AddOwner(
            typeof(RCTWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnVisualChanged));

    public RemapColors RemapColor
    {
        get { return (RemapColors)GetValue(RemapColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RemapColorProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnVisualChanged(
        DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("RCTWindow.OnVisualChanged: {0}", ((RCTWindow)obj).RemapColor);
    }
}
```